# Creating temporary array when declared in a module

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran

I do not understand why `gfortran` creates a temporary array only in one case. Consider the following program

```
program temporary_arrays
  use Mvars, only       : am
  use Mtemporaries, only: create_matrix
  implicit none
  integer, parameter    :: dp = kind(1.d0), n = 3
  real(dp), allocatable :: bm(:, :)
  
  allocate(am(n, n), bm(n, n))

  ! -- temporary array is created --
  am = create_matrix(n)

  ! -- no temporary array --
  bm = create_matrix(n)
  
end program temporary_arrays

!------------------------
module Mtemporaries

contains
  function create_matrix(n) result(A)
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0)
    integer  :: n
    real(dp) :: a(n, n)
    A = 0.d0
  end function create_matrix

end module Mtemporaries  

!------------------------
module Mvars
  implicit none
  integer, parameter       :: dp = kind(1.d0)
  real(dp), allocatable    :: am(:, :)
  
end module Mvars
```

When compiled with `gfortran` (GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 13.2.0) 13.2.0 Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.) with the `-Warray-temporaries` option, I get that temporary array is created only in one case, namely when the array is declared in a different module. No such warning when the array is declared in the main program.

I would like to know the logic behind and how to deal with this problem, i.e., avoid creation of temporary arrays.

Comment: The Intel compiler doesn't create a temporary array on this code. It's hard to say why gfortran is able to optimize out the temporary array in one case and not in the other case. It's a quality of implementation issue...

Comment: @PierU What is the version of your compiler?

Comment: In view of the comment by @PierU,  It would be nice to see how other compilers perform.

Comment: When performances really matter I tend to avoid functions returning arrays and prefer writing subroutines instead, precisely because it’s difficult to be sure how compilers will deal with them.

Comment: @PierU This (using subroutines) I was doing for a long time. I remember codes (e.g. Gaussian) containing subroutines with > 50 arguments. But then recently, the idea of functional programming paradigm attracted me. In fact, fortran has very rudimentary functional features. And it seems they are not functional at all! :(

Comment: I don't get your point. If you have a subroutine with 50 arguments, the equivalent function will have 49 arguments, it's not really simpler. Having functions that return complex objects looks attractive, but you have to imagine what he means at the compiler level. Scalars can be kept in registers before before being assigned to whatever variable or directly used in an expression, but arrays? The optimization is much more complicated.

Comment: I tested with ifort 2021

Comment: @PierU There books written about the advantages of functional programming , and languages (Haskell, Scala) built around this paradigm. In fortran, the `pure` attribute is used to facilitate the compiler in e.g. loop unrolling. With subroutines, side effects are elevated to a norm. I would even claim, if developers of gfortran do not know how to optimise functions, they can automatically and internally promote them to subroutines. But user should be provided with a clear interface.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256845/discussion-between-pieru-and-yarchik).

Comment: Talking about purity, adding the `intent(in)` attribute to the argument `n` of the function, even without explicitly declaring the function as `pure`, is enough to avoid the temporary array here: https://godbolt.org/z/7cqY839bM , even without having to explicitely declare the function as `pure`.

Comment: @steve Calm down, it was absolutly not what I meant. All compilers have some QoI issues, or bugs, and it's legitimate to discuss them. My main point here is that it was not a bug.